# Lights not working on HP msa 2040

Tags: raid, configuration, hp, hp-modular-smart-array

I have HP MSA 2040, it has total of 12 disks 3 of the disk lights are off. How to check the issue? Or are they off due to any configuration or raid?

Another question how to check what raid is configured on HP MSA 2040?

Comment: ask a more concrete question please. Yours can now be understood in several ways. Is your question ' <a more concrete type> of light on a HP MSA 2040 are off, what does it mean?'

Comment: And raise your other query in an other question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you logged into the management interface? that'll tell you if you have any hardware issues or if those disks just aren't assigned to a VDISK yet or not - there's no other way really, just connect to it and see.

By the way, don't be too fast to update the firmware on the 1040/2040's at the moment, HPE have been releasing some very buggy versions of firmware for these devices for the last few months - they keep 'pulling' updates, if you don't need to update then wait for a few months to see if things have settled down.